# aspx element is not recognized in code behind (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I created an element with runat="server" tag but i cannot be recognized in the code behind.("time" is not recognized)

> aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="game.aspx.cs" Inherits="RapidTyper.game" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
        <div runat="server">
    <a runat="server" id="time"></a>
        </div>
    <asp:Button ID="UpdateResults" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:none;" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="" />
```

> code behind

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int score = time.Text;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the element `<a runat="server" id="time"></a>` is not an asp.net element but an [Html element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmllink?view=netframework-4.8) that have no `Text` property.

You can use the LinkButton `<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="time2"></asp:LinkButton>` that renders `<a>` Tag and have Text property.

- also the `<a>` Tag is not an input element and is not post back anything - so the `score = time.Text` is not going to get anything other than the one you have all ready set previously.

Answer (score 0):

What Aristos has written is correct, but your problems go deeper than this.  In order to use elements like `<asp:Button />` you need to place them within a form which in turn needs to be within a `<body>` .  At the very least you need something like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="eShop.test" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="time" />
        </div>
    <asp:Button ID="UpdateResults" runat="server" OnClick="UpdateResults_Click" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note That I have assumed that you also need something like an `<asp:TextBox>`.  I presume this should be some sort of a user input?  Finally you will not be able to simply do `int score = time.Text` since Text is a string.  At the very least you need `int score = int.Parse(time.Text)` but this will only work, if the box contains an actual integer.  Anything else will throw an error.  Instead you should look at `int.TryParse`